# Set a form as a property in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular form where items are generated dynamically (based on a report type). For the form items that may conditionally be present, it seems overly difficult to try and bind these to model properties. I would like to declare a form, with variable components (given names, values, etc), and access these through one form property.

This has proven to be a little difficult and I've run into various errors in this approach.

Declaring the form with just a property binding: (form `[(nGModel)]="testForm"` and ts: `testForm: form` yields

"If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions"

If I declare a name for the form: (form `[(nGModel)]="testForm" name="blah"`), I get the following error

**"No value accessor for form control with name: 'blah'"**

I tried adding 'providers: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR' to the component declaration, but this gives compile error that the inectiontoken is missing x properties

What is the most direct way to solve this problem (want to set entire form as property to get form controls ie this.paramsForm.getControl or something like that to get a list of these form items). Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to angular if that's not clear

Comment: What you need is Reactive Form. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Instead of name property us formControlName that will solve your problem.

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: If you are using Reactive Form, you can define formControlName="property". ngModel is not required in reactive Form, its been used on Template Driven Form

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Reactive form then you need to declare `formControlName` in your HTML file like below on your `input` field, you do not need to add ngModel here

```
<input type="text"  formControlName="nameCtrl" >
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive Form, you can define formControlName="property". ngModel is not required in reactive Form, its been used on Template Driven Form.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
   <input type="text" formControlName="username"/>
</form>
```